# Direct Citation With Author's First Letter Capitalized

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm trying to make a direct citation on my text, where I need only the first letter of the author's name to be capitalized.

For some reason natbib's [\Citet](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) (with capital C) does not capitalize the first letter of the in-text citation, hence \citet and \Citet have the exact same output:

### Current scenario

```
\citet[p. 32]{Christensen1997} --> CHRISTENSEN (1997, p. 32)    
\Citet[p. 32]{Christensen1997} --> CHRISTENSEN (2013, p. 32)
```

### Intended output

```
\Citet[p.32]{Christensen1997} --> Christensen (1997, p. 32)
```

Please note that this has to be true also when I don't add the page number:

```
\Citet{Christensen1997} --> Christensen (1997)
```

Here's the entry on my .bib file

```
@book{Christensen1997,
address = {Boston},
author = {Christensen, Clayton M},
booktitle = {The management of innovation and change series},
publisher = {Harvard Business School Press},
title = {{The Innovator's Dilemma: When New Technologies Cause Great Firms to Fail}},
year = {1997}
}
```

The bibliography style I'm using is ABNT ([link](https://github.com/fcecagno/masters-ti/blob/master/abnt.bst))

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: We need to know the bib style you're calling.

Comment: I'm using ABNT - https://github.com/fcecagno/masters-ti/blob/master/abnt.bst

Comment: Can you please prepare a minimal example of code? From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can change line 383 of abnt.bst, inside the function `format.family.names`, from

```
        "u" change.case$
```

to

```
        "t" change.case$
```

This will change the string used in citation commands, but not affect the printing in the bibliography.  The "u" made the sting upper case; "t" will make it title case.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abnt}

\begin{document}

\citet{Christensen1997}

\Citet{Christensen1997}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\end{document}
```

If you use the `\citeauthor*` command you should make a similar change to the function `format.family.names.all`.

Depending on your actual requirements, you might prefer to make the string lowercase using `"l"` instead of `"t"`.  Then `\citet` will give the name in lower case and `\Citet` will have the first letter capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of name formatting commands in lines 319-419

```
%==============================================================================
% Formata uma lista de nomes.
%
% Parm:
%    os nomes a serem formatados
%==============================================================================
FUNCTION {format.names}
{
    duplicate$ num.names$ 'n :=
    #1 'i :=
    "" 'names :=

    {i n #1 + <}
    {
        duplicate$ duplicate$ i "{ll}{~jj}" format.name$
        duplicate$ "others" =
        n #3 >
        i #2 =
        and
        or
        {
            pop$ pop$ names " et~al." *
            n 'i :=
        }{
            "u" change.case$ swap$
            i "{, f.}{~vv}" format.name$ *
            names swap$ add.to.namelist
        } if$ 'names :=
        #1 i + 'i :=
    } while$
    pop$
    names
    duplicate$ #-1 #1 substring$ "." = {
        #-2 global.max$ substring$
        "\@." *
    }
        'skip$
    if$
}

%==============================================================================
% Formata uma lista de sobrenomes.
%
% Parm:
%    os nomes a serem formatados
%==============================================================================
FUNCTION {format.family.names}
{
    duplicate$ num.names$ 'n :=
    #1 'i :=
    "" 'names :=

    {i n #1 + <}
    {
        duplicate$ i "{ll}{~jj}" format.name$
        duplicate$ "others" =
        n #3 >
        i #2 =
        and
        or
        {
            pop$ names " et~al." *
            n 'i :=
        }{
            "u" change.case$
            names swap$ add.to.namelist
        } if$ 'names :=
        #1 i + 'i :=
    } while$
    pop$
    names
}

%==============================================================================
% Formata uma lista de sobrenomes com todos os autores.
%
% Parm:
%    os nomes a serem formatados
%==============================================================================
FUNCTION {format.family.names.all}
{
    duplicate$ num.names$ 'n :=
    #1 'i :=
    "" 'names :=

    {i n #1 + <}
    {
        duplicate$ i "{ll}{~jj}" format.name$
        duplicate$ "others" =
        {
            pop$ names " et~al." *
            n 'i :=
        }{
            "u" change.case$
            names swap$ add.to.namelist
        } if$ 'names :=
        #1 i + 'i :=
    } while$
    pop$
    names
}
```

I do not really know the .bst language, but I think just removing the `change.case$` commands may solve your problem.